# How to fetch only last 1 hour entries from a SQL Server or Oracle table?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, datetime, time

I have a log table where I have a date column `log_date` value like 2021-03-02 07:51:41.000 in the format.

My requirement is that on click of a button I want to list out of the log entries from the last hour.

I searched SO and find out the below query which is for MySQL.
I need two separate T-SQL queries that should work on SQL Server and Oracle for my requirement since the common query is not possible.

What is the best way to fetch the last 1 hour records from the log table for SQL and Oracle (separate query)?

```
select count(*) as cnt
from  log
where log_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

Comment: There is no solution that will work for both oracle and sql server

Comment: You say you want "separate T-SQL queries" but you can't run a T-SQL query against an Oracle database.  Do you want separate SQL queries, one in Oracle's dialect of SQL and one in SQL Server's SQL dialect?

Comment: @JustinCave I am going to use this query on Hibernate so i will check the db source and build two different query.

Comment: I'm probably missing something...  If you're using Hibernate, you're presumably writing a Java application to retrieve the data.  Rather than having different queries for three different databases, it would make more sense to me to write a single query with a bind variable, calculate the value of that bind variable in Java, and pass it along.  Then you don't have to deal with three different SQL dialects for performing date arithmetic.  You can just use one Java dialect for doing so.

Comment: As an aside, if the column in oracle is a DATE data type, then it is NOT "in the format 2021-03-02 07:51:41.000"  Oracle DATEs and TIMESTAMPs are an internal binary format.  The "format" you mention is the result of the client to an implicit or explicit to_char on the date column, to produce a character string for display and use by humans who recognize the character string as representing a date and time.  And the format you show has decimal fractions of seconds, so must represent a TIMESTAMP, not a DATE.

Answer (score 1):

Create a database *view* in each of your databases, that filter only teh last hour of the log table.

here an example for Oracle

```
create view log_last_hour as
select * 
from log
where log_date >= sysdate - interval '1' hour;
```

Than you can use a single simple query that is *database independent*

Example

```
select count(*) from log_last_hour
```